# jQuery live chain events click: show(callback) no effect - bug?

Tags: jquery, callback, live, show

I'm struggling with this piece of code and can't understand if it's a bug or bad coding?! Any help is much appreciated.

```
$('.showDiv').live({
  click: function () {
    $('#myDiv').show(function () {
      // DO SOMETHING AFTER SHOW DIV COMPLETES
      // THE PROBLEM IS THAT I CAN'T MAKE DIV SIMPLY SHOW WITHOUT EFFECT!
    });
  }, mouseenter: function () {
    // ...
  }, mouseleave: function () {
    // ...
  }
});
```

The chain events all work well (click:, mouseenter:, mouseleave:) but the `$('#myDiv').show(function () {...}` always performs the show with the default 'swing' which messes up what I need - simply show the div with no effect and no delay!

Curiously if I don't use any callback function, just `$('#myDiv').show();` the div shows as I want - immediately and with no effect... I wonder if it's a bug?

I've tried with args in the show like `$('#myDiv').show(100, function () {...}` and `$('#myDiv').show(0, '', function () {...}` but the div always show up with the swing effect.

Note: Since live is to become depreciated I've also tried with `.on()` but the result is exactly the same.

Any help or tip?
Thanks.

Comment: `live` was deprecated in 1.7. It's been removed in 1.9. Don't use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should switch to `.on`, but that has nothing to do with it.

If you look at the documentation for [`.show`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) you will see that there is no form of the method that has a callback as the first argument.

If you don't want any animation to be done, then there's no reason have a callback since the operation completes instantly.  It only makes sense to have a callback if you need it to happen after the asynchronous animation completes.

If you *really* wanted, you could use `.show(0, function () { ... })`, but it really makes no sense.

Comment: I understand what you mean but in my case I want to show the div and only then request some data from another page. But even with `.show(0, function () { ... })` it still shows the div with the swing effect. Any suggestion on other method to show div first and only then perform the request to the other page?

Comment: @ElEme: You're overcomplicating this. Just call. `.show();` (no arguments), and then perform the request. As both Explosion Pills and Matt ball have pointed out, `show` with no arguments happens **immediately**, with no animation.

Comment: @all: Thank's for the replies and help.

Answer (score 3):

Don't pass *any* argument to `.show()`, [as documented](http://api.jquery.com/show/), and as your experimenting revealed.

> With no parameters, the `.show()` method is the simplest way to display an element... The matched elements will be revealed immediately, with no animation.

Answer (score -1):

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers.

check [jQuery .on documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

**UPDATE**

```
$('.showDiv').live({
 click: function () {
   $('#myDiv').show(0,function () {
  // pass duration parameter first. 0 milisec 
  alert('myDiv is visible.');
});
 }, mouseenter: function () {
// ...
 }, mouseleave: function () {
// ...
 }
});
```